# Is it possible to tweak meta tag for theme-color so it works on regular windows chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, themes, meta-tags, color-scheme

I am using meta tags for theme-color, and they work great on mobile browsers for android or iOS mobile devices but I want MY tab to be a different color than others that are open in chrome, safari or firefox on regular sized computers and laptops.

Is there a way?